# Diagnosing PSU/Motherboard issues with Shuttle's proprietary ATX connector

Tags: power-supply, atx, shuttle

I have a Shuttle SN25P that won't power on at all - fans, no lights. The cable and power have been checked and the PSU switch is in the on position. I need to figure out if the motherboard or PSU are damaged, however Shuttle motherboards and PSUs don't use the standard 20 pin ATX connector/ 4 pin P4 connector. Instead they feature an "8-pin ATX3" and "6-pin CN5" connector instead.

Is there a way to test/power a Shuttle motherboard using a regular ATX power supply?

Comment: Does it beep at all? does the PSU fan turn on?

Comment: You can always locate a pinout of the connectors, although it might take a bit of searching. Then short PS_ON to GRND and use a voltmeter to check the various outputs.